# manipulating select boxes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

i want to change the font of the page using jquery,so here goes

html:

```
<p>Content Font:</p>
<select name="content_fonts">
<option value="volvo">Arial</option>
<option value="saab">Gerogia</option>
<option value="fiat" selected="selected">Times New Roman</option>
<option value="audi">verdana</option>
</select>
```

jquery:

```
$('#contant_fonts').click(function(){
   $('.leftpanel').css('font-family',"Times New Roman", Times, serif"));
});
```

but it deosnt seem to work thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need some quote adjustment and your selector is off, like this:

```
$('select[name="content_fonts"]').click(function(){
   $('.leftpanel').css('font-family','"Times New Roman", Times, serif');
});
```

Though what I *think* you're after is this:

```
$('select[name="content_fonts"]').change(function(){
    $('.leftpanel').css('font-family', $(this).find(":selected").text());
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/3jwsp/).

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at your code

```
$('.leftpanel').css('font-family',"Times New Roman", Times, serif"));
```

the second argumentto `css` is a string  so If you need to pass Double Quotes in that string that shouldn't break the argument itself.

```
$('.leftpanel').css('font-family','"Times New Roman", Times, serif'));
```

see Nick Craver's Answer.

or you can even escape (`\"`) the Double quotes.

The Problem lies in your quotes not in jQuery. or Javascript.